# How should I bid farewell to a superior?

Tags: expressions, politeness, set-phrases, culture, business-japanese

My boss is leaving soon after years of service.  What would be a good way for me to express my gratitude for all of his guidance and help?

I am somewhat familiar with the expression お世話になりました but am unsure if this is an appropriate occasion to use it.  Are there other phrases that would be more suitable in a corporate environment?

Comment: Don't forget to add ありがとうございました like... 長い間、(いろいろと)お世話になって(orなりまして)、(本当に)ありがとうございました ^^

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would say the expression お世話になりました is spot on. Especially since you are trying to express gratitude for guidance, which is contained in the word 世話 "looking after; help; aid; assistance". Moreover, お世話になりました is formal and certainly suitable for a corporate environment. To adapt it to your situation, you could say, e.g.

> 長い間お世話になりました。